# How to stop a large query if it has too many rows in PostgreSQL using Jdbc?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc

We run user submitted queries which can potentially return a large result set.

In order to avoid memory issues, we would like to detect these cases and cancel the query. The user then is expected to modify the query.

We already use `PreparedStatement#setFetchSize()` to scroll the result set and process a large result set incrementally.
However, when the result set is too large, we would like to avoid bringing even the first results over the network or any **other unnecessary work as much as possible** on the client side and on the database side.

Doing a `SELECT COUNT(*)...` beforehand just degrades the performance of the expected case where the queries behave nicely in general.

Is there a way for postgres to tell the expected result set size?

Comment: you can run explain without analyze ahead to check estimated rows and cost

Comment: What if you simply limit the maximum size using `PreparedStatement.setMaxRows()` ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's just limits the returned set and silently drops the rest, it doesn't prevent you from doing extra work of fetching the results before realizing you have too many.

Comment: @vao thanks, discussing this in thwiegan's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate).

They are doing an estimate with a database procedure:

```
CREATE FUNCTION count_estimate(query text) RETURNS INTEGER AS
$func$
DECLARE
    rec   record;
    ROWS  INTEGER;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN EXECUTE 'EXPLAIN ' || query LOOP
        ROWS := SUBSTRING(rec."QUERY PLAN" FROM ' rows=([[:digit:]]+)');
        EXIT WHEN ROWS IS NOT NULL;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN ROWS;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It uses the `EXPLAIN` command of PGSQL to estimate the returned rowcount.

Comment: Nice, however the estimate is not guaranteed to be less than the actual result. The estimate may be bigger than the maximum allowed results but the actual result may be much less, and the query should run. Up voted chase it may be eventually applicable an useful for other situations.

Comment: @Sagi You could use it and in edge cases where the estimate might prove not accurate enough use select count(*)

Comment: sounds plausible. I'll check counts for estimates that are bigger or smaller but close to the maximum allowed. That should help in most cases. Thanks.